# Adding bits, simpler

Tags: c, bitwise, bitset

Considering that two bitsets are provided in the form of strings, `char a[]` and `char b[]`, as in the code below. And the task of add that bitsets is given. I take it and wrote the following to sum the two bitsets:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int carry = 0;
char result(char r, int c) {
    char R = '0';
    if (carry) {
        if (c) {
            R = '0';
            carry = 1;
        } else {
            R = r == '0' ? '1' : '0';
            carry = R == '0' ? 1 : 0;
        }
    } else {
        if (c) {
            R = '0';
            carry = 1;
        } else {
            R = r;
            carry = 0;
        }
    }
    return R;
}

char sum(int x, int y) {
    char r = '0';
    if (x ^ y) 
        r = result('1', 0);
    else if (x & y)
        r = result('0', 1);
    else 
        r = result('0', 0);
    return r;
}

int main() { 
    char a[] = "01";
    char b[] = "01";
    char c[] = "00";
    for (int i = strlen(c)-1; i > -1; i--) 
        c[i] = sum(a[i] == '0' ? 0 : 1, b[i] == '0' ? 0 : 1);
    printf("%s\n", c);
}
```

Is it possible to make it simpler?

Comment: Are `a` and `b` guaranteed to be the same length?  What about if the top bit carries?  Should `c` be extended by 1 character?

Comment: An answer even without that level of sophistication will be appreciated.

Comment: I find the code very difficult to follow, mainly because of the poor (nondescript) naming choices, but also because of the lack of a clear explanation of what problem it is supposed to be solving (either in comments or in the body of the question). That's kind of my pseudo-review; I don't have the time or desire to think much harder about what it's supposed to be doing. In other words—I'd hand this back for a revision straight-away, but I don't think that makes a suitable answer here.

Answer (score 2):

OP's approach is very tangled.

No provisions are made for a final carry-out of the sum.

`char result(char r, int c) {` should at least been used description names: `char add_digit_carry(char digit, int carry) {`

`for (int i = strlen(c)-1; i > -1; i--)` --> Little things like `i >= 0;` are certainly easier to follow.

`strlen()` returns type `size_t`.  Array indexing and sizing is best done with that type.

---

The basic way to add strings is just like grade-school math:  add the 1 places, form the sum and carry.  Then add the next most significant column along with the carry.  Repeat for all digits and consider a carry out.

Assuming memory issues are not a big concern ....

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

// c = a + b
char *KFM_add(char *c, size_t c_size, const char *a, const char *b, int base) {
  assert(base >= 2 && base <= 10 && c_size > 0);
  size_t a_end = strlen(a);
  size_t b_end = strlen(b);
  size_t c_end = c_size - 1;

  c[c_end] = '\0';
  int carry = 0;

  while (a_end > 0 || b_end > 0 || carry > 0) {
    int sum = carry;
    if (a_end > 0) {
      sum += a[--a_end] - '0';
    }
    if (b_end > 0) {
      sum += b[--b_end] - '0';
    }
    assert(c_end > 0);
    c[--c_end] = sum % base + '0';
    carry = sum / base;
  }

  // return memmove(&c[0], &c[c_end], c_end); // Corrected code @JS1
  return memmove(&c[0], &c[c_end], c_size - c_end);
}

#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  char a[] = "111";
  char b[] = "01";
  char c[80];

  puts(KFM_add(c, sizeof c, a, b, 2));  // Output 1000
}
```

Should one want to explore binary addition closer:

```
#include <stdbool.h>
  ...
  bool carry = 0;
  while (a_end > 0 || b_end > 0 || carry > 0) {
    bool a_bit = (a_end > 0) ? (a[--a_end] - '0') : false;
    bool b_bit = (b_end > 0) ? (b[--b_end] - '0') : false;
    assert(c_end > 0);
    c[--c_end] = (a_bit ^ b_bit ^ carry) + '0';
    carry = (a_bit & b_bit) | (b_bit & carry) | (carry & a_bit);
  }
  ...
```

Comment: What's the meaning of `F`, `K` and `M` in `FKM_add`?

Comment: @KcFnMi FKM is a shorted form of KcFnMi, that was inadvertently re-ordered..